# Can I set editor.tokenColorCustomizations inside a VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a language support plugin for a proprietary language I use at work. We access properties of deeply nested objects a lot, e.g. `This.isa.Really.Long.Variable.Name.ActualValue` so the code gets really dense with these. My idea was to apply a TextMate scope to everything before the last dot and change the color to a partially transparent white so it fades into the background.

I've successfully added a rule in my editor settings to change the color of a TextMate scope that I created.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [{
    "scope": "support.variable.long.myLang",
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#ffffff90",
      "fontStyle": "italic"
    }
  }]
}
```

However, adding this rule to "configurationDefaults" in my extension doesn't work and it warns "Unknown editor configuration setting". I can set other editor settings just fine.

Is there a way to do this?
Or is there already a TextMate scope that would generally correlate to faded out text?
Or any other way to fade/hide part of a line in VScode?

Comment: I don't think you can add coloring in your language extension. You  define the scopes in there and then the theme engine colors it using fallback scopes.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible, here I give you an example of my extension, defining colors to my new scopes. Works correctly.

```
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
      "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": "my-extension.constants",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#b180a9"
            }
          },
          {
            "scope": "my-extension.variables",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#2ebe82"
            }
          },
          {
            "scope": "my-extension.translations",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#64a1f1"
            }
          },
          {
            "scope": "my-extension.store",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#b3b6b9"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this overwrite other `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"` the user may have?  In other words, is that setting `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"` completely replaced or are the the new `textMateRules` merged?

Comment: They merge, but in case of having a duplicate scope, the one configured in the user settings prevails.

Comment: @CarlosTenorioPérez, they don't seem to merge. Have you tried this, or do you have a reference?

Comment: I can verify that they do not merge, unfortunately. Stuck on the same problem.